# Navigating the while loop

Tags: c++

I'm making a sort of hang-man type game and have things working pretty well apart from having a message appear when the player does not guess a letter in the phrase. If they guess a number that's in the phrase, the phrase "nice" appears as normal. However, with the wrong letter, it just prints out "wrong" 10 times (which is what I have set in my while loop).

I'd like to understand why this is occuring. I have the while loop setup to continue until the misses reach 10, or the phrase is complete. But since my message to the player is within a for loop within the while loop, why is it printing multiple times still?

I suspect this is a scope issue (clearly), but I'm having trouble understanding why the "right" print is working, but the "wrong" prints 10 times. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include "ufo_functions.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main() {

    string phrase = "spicyonion";
    string dashes = "----------";
    char guess;
    int misses = 0;


    greet();
    cout<<dashes<<"\n";

    while (misses < 10 && dashes != phrase) {
        display_misses(misses);
        cout<<"What is your guess? Enter here: ";
        cin>>guess;


        for (int i=0; i<phrase.length(); i++) {
            if (guess == phrase[i]) {
                cout<<"Nice!\n";
                dashes[i] = guess;
            } else {
                cout<<"WRONG.\n";
                misses++;
            }
        }
        cout<<dashes<<"\n";

    }

    end_game(phrase, dashes);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since this behaviour is consistent, run the program in a debugger and step though a few loops of the "wrong" case and watch what happens. You'll probably have it figured out before anyone can write a decent answer.

Comment: guessing `'i'` produce misses for each letter of `"spcyonon"` (and 2 successes)... Your `std::cout` should be after the loop, not inside (and so you have to keep replacement success).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check for matches for every letter in the phrase in a for-loop. So if a guess matches nothing, it will miss 10 times so it prints out "WRONG." ten times. Also correct guess of repeating letters will also print out that many "NICE!". You probably just want to declare a int flag = 0 just before the for-loop to set to 1 for correct guesses. You check for the value of this flag after the for-loop so as to print the "WRONG." or "NICE!" once.

Comment: This helped, thank you. I opted for a bool variable that would mark the variable true if the guess was correct, then created a separate if-statement if it was true. Then lastly changed the variable back to false at the end of the while loop before the loop begins again.